# Metadata file 'C:\MyProject\some.dll" could not be found and it says file location as CSC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

i referred many thread related to this error and nothing is solving my issue.

I cleaned and rebuild the solution and checked build checkbox enabled for all project and did individual build. but no luck :(

**Error**

```
Metadata file 'C:\MyProject\some.dll" could not be found. File : CSC
```

Comment: Please include the entire error message in your question.

Comment: I have updated the error message.

Comment: You could try deleting and then re-adding the reference to the project.

Comment: I have tried now and no luck :(

Comment: You are probably trying .NET Native. You may want to disable that.